# Is there a way to access a method by type definition?

Tags: julia

I am trying to call a function using my struct type but also want it available when calling with a value type.  Is there a way to make the code work?

```
struct MyStruct
    names
    function MyStruct()
        names = colnames(MyStruct) # this doesnt work
        new(names)
    end
end

colnames(T::MyStruct) = ["A", "B"]


m = MyStruct()
colnames(m) # This should also work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
colnames(::Type{MyStruct}) = ["A", "B"]
colnames(::MyStruct) = colnames(MyStruct)
```

(I called first method in the second to ensure that you define the contents of the returned vector only in one place)

Comment: Ah I see, how about if I want the second function to be generic and do that for any passed type that is a child of say AbstractMyStruct?

Comment: Try `colnames(x::AbstractMyStruct) = colnames(typeof(x))`